# Байт-код в PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Как можно получить байт-код сценария PowerShell? Или как его можно вытащить из памяти?

Comment: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PS2EXE-Convert-PowerShell-9e4e07f1